# Mysql error while updating

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web-applications, codeigniter-2

**Error** looks something like this:

> Unknown column 'resignation_id='158'' in 'where clause'

`UPDATE pr_temporary_absconding_checklists SET completion_status = 'pending' WHEREresignation_id='158' AND checklist_id='4'`

My model code is:

```html
function submit_absconding_checklist($post_array, $idss) {

  $this->load->database();
  $ids = $this->uri->segment(4);
  $where = "resignation_id='$ids' AND checklist_id='$idss'";
  $this->db->where($where);
  $dbdata = array(
    "completion_status" => $post_array['completion_status']
  );

  $this->db->update('pr_temporary_absconding_checklists', $dbdata);
  print_r($query);
  die;
  /**
   * if required add this code here to check
   *
   * echo $this->db->last_query();
   */
  return 'Checklist updated successfully';
}
```

Also attached table image[image]:

Comment: misplaced backtick in the sql according to the final sql statement ~ there appears to be a backtick surrounding all of "resignation_id='158'"

Comment: Your table tells you are using resignation_id1 instead of resignation_id.
Change it.

Comment: What @Manish? It's Correct.

Comment: no its only for sorting.. it has nothing to do with the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write you query in Active Record format as

```
$this->db->set("completion_statuscompletion_status", $post_array['completion_status']);
$this->db->where("resignation_id", $ids);
$this->db->where("checklist_id", $idss);
$this->db->update("pr_temporary_absconding_checklists");
$afftectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backticks around `resignation_id='158'` in your query.

It should look like this :

```
UPDATE `pr_temporary_absconding_checklists` SET `completion_status` = 'pending' WHERE `resignation_id`='158' AND `checklist_id`='4'
```

Model code :

```
function submit_absconding_checklist($post_array, $idss) {

  $this->load->database();
  $ids = $this->uri->segment(4);
  $this->db->where('resignation_id', $ids); // UPDATED
  $this->db->where('checklist_id', $idss); // UPDATED
  $dbdata = array(
    "completion_status" => $post_array['completion_status']
  );

  $this->db->update('pr_temporary_absconding_checklists', $dbdata);
  print_r($query);
  die;
  /**
   * if required add this code here to check
   *
   * echo $this->db->last_query();
   */
  return 'Checklist updated successfully';
}
```

Comment: please give the query as there are variable substitutions

Comment: I added the model code, with the correct use of `$this->db->where()`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$data = array(
    'completion_status' => $post_array['completion_status']
);

$this->db->where('resignation_id', $ids);
$this->db->where('checklist_id', $idss);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: Unknown column 'resignation_id='158'' in 'where clause'

UPDATE pr_temporary_absconding_checklists SET `completion_status` = NULL WHERE `resignation_id='158'` AND checklist_id='4'

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code.

```
function submit_absconding_checklist($post_array, $idss) {
    $this->load->database();
    $ids = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $dbdata["completion_status"] = $post_array['completion_status'];
    $this->db->update("pr_temporary_absconding_checklists", $dbdata, array('resignation_id' => $ids,'checklist_id'=>$idss));

    print_r($query);
    die;
    /**
      * if required add this code here to check
      *
      * echo $this->db->last_query();
    */
    return 'Checklist updated successfully';
  }
```